# call clone() in my own class

Tags: java, clone

I know that there is a `clone()` method in **Object** class which is declared as `protected`, so that means I can call `clone()` in my own class since every class inherits from **Object** class, for example :

```
public class CloneTest
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Employee employee1 = new Employee(...);
        Employee employee2 = employee1.clone(); // but here has 2 errors
    }
}

class Employee
{
    ...
}
```

first error is something about "access protected in Object"
second error is "incompatible type"
Why these errors happen ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [clone method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29) returns an Object if not overridden. So you must cast the result :

```
Employee employee2 = (Employee) employee1.clone();
```

The first error is related to the content of the Employee class, that we don't see. Does it override the clone method ? It should, that's the condition to have it accessible from other classes that the called class.

Comment: do you mean that if I don't override the `clone()` method in Employee class, it will generates an error ? but I think that `clone()` is a **protected** method in **Object** class, so I can use it my CloneTest class (because CloneTest is a subclass of Object)

Comment: Yes, you must override it. This will make it accessible (you may make it public if you wish). A method in CloneTest cannot call a protected method of the Object class called on Employee.

Comment: Casting should be done in the clone() method not by the client

Comment: @dcernahoschi Both are possible. I was explaining the 2 errors. And yes, you should return an Employee if you're writing a clone method in a modern jdk.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Employee` class should look something like this for `clone()` to work:

```
public class Employee implements Cloneable {
    ...

    public Employee clone() {
        try {
            return (Employee) super.clone();
        }
        catch(CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            throe new IllegalStateException("I forgot to implement cloneable");
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

The first error is because `clone` has protected access in the `Object` class and the second one is because it returns `Object` by default.

Answer (score 0):

The first error is because `.clone` is protected in the Object class. It's not public.`

The only way to get access to an object's `.clone()` method is to know it has a compile-time type that has a public `.clone()` method.

Override `clone` method in `Employee` Class

```
 class Employee implements Cloneable
{
   @Override
   protected Employee clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return (Employee)super.clone();
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a few things in order to use the clone method. See: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=71